# OpenGL shaders with dynamic objects

Tags: opengl

I want to create a program with OpenGL shaders which renders a number of coloured *blobs* moving around on the screen. Now if the number of blobs was fixed, then I would create a single VAO with one VBO for each blob's vertex positions, and one VBO for each blob's vertex colours. On each frame, I would then update the vertex positions in the VBO, and then render the vertices accordingly.

However, in my program, the number of blobs is not fixed. There is a button which the user can press which deletes blobs, and another button which creates new blobs. Therefore, my solution above does not work because, in time, I will not want to draw all the vertices in the VBOs, and furthermore I will want to add extra vertices to the VBOs.

What is the solution to this? Should I create new VBOs on every frame according to the number of blobs that currently exist at that time (seems slow...)? Or should I increase the size of the VBOs every time a new blob is created (seems inefficient in memory, and in any case, how do I *not* draw the deleted blobs...)? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Why does each blob have individual vertex positions and colors?

Comment: Because all blobs are different shapes and have a unique colour. And if they had the same vertex positions and colours, then each blob would just be drawn on top of each other, no?

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Each blob's color can be a uniform value assigned at render time. The shape can be built through in-shader animation rather than through modifying the vertices in the buffers. So why does each blob have individual vertex positions and colors?

Comment: `And if they had the same vertex positions and colours, then each blob would just be drawn on top of each other, no?` Do you create a whole new cube just to draw a cube in a different spot? No; that's what transformations are for: to draw things in a different place.

Comment: Yes I understand about the transformation, but all blobs have different shapes, so they need to have their own unique set of vertex positions. As for modifying the position of each blob, I was just following a tutorial which I then extended to allow the blob positions to be changed. But I see that I could also do that with a transformation in the shader, which would be more efficient. Thanks! However, this doesn't solve the problem I have with a dynamic set of blobs....